# Error with pip : pip-compile does not support URLs as packages

Tags: python, pip, pip-tools

I'm using `pip` with `pip-compile` (installed this way: `pip install pip-tools`)

I got the following error when I run the `pip-compile -v` command:

> **pip-compile does not support URLs as packages**, unless they are editable. Perhaps add -e option? (constraint was:
>   aldryn-django==1.8.7.0 from
>   https://control.aldyn.com/api/v1/apps/serve/aldryn-django/1.8.7.0/592213b1-e515-4447-8ef0-850713571a42/aldryn-django-1.8.7.0.tar.gz#egg=aldryn-django==1.8.7.0
>   (from -r requirements.in (line 2)))

I have tried with the `-e` option, but this causes another problem.

> pip.exceptions.InstallationError: https://control.aldryn.com/api/v1/apps/serve/aldryn-django/1.8.7.0/592213b1-e515-4447-8ef0-850713571a42/aldryn-django-1.8.7.0.tar.gz#egg=aldryn-django==1.8.7.0 should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+

Below is an short extract of my `requirements.in` file:

```
\# <INSTALLED_ADDONS>  # Warning: text inside the INSTALLED_ADDONS tags is auto-generated. Manual changes will be overwritten.
https://control.aldryn.com/api/v1/apps/serve/aldryn-django/1.8.7.0/592213b1-e515-4447-8ef0-850713571a42/aldryn-django-1.8.7.0.tar.gz#egg=aldryn-django==1.8.7.0
...
\# </INSTALLED_ADDONS>
```

I'm using Docker container based on the `python:2.7-slim` image.

The `requirements.in` work well on one other similar docker container.

I don't know why on mine, `pip-compile` does not work...

Have you any idea?

Comment: I got this error message : pip.exceptions.InstallationError: https://control.aldryn.com/api/v1/apps/serve/aldryn-django/1.8.7.0/592213b1-e515-4447-8ef0-850713571a42/aldryn-django-1.8.7.0.tar.gz#egg=aldryn-django==1.8.7.0 should either be a path to a local project or a VCS url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+

Here is an extract of my **requirements.in** : -e https://control.aldryn.com/api/v1/apps/serve/aldryn-django/1.8.7.0/592213b1-e515-4447-8ef0-850713571a42/aldryn-django-1.8.7.0.tar.gz#egg=aldryn-django==1.8.7.0

Comment: It's already the case, It's a copy / past cut. Here is my requirements file : -e https://control.aldryn.com/api/v1/apps/serve/aldryn-django/1.8.7.0/592213b1-e515-4447-8ef0-850713571a42/aldryn-django-1.8.7.0.tar.gz#egg=aldryn-django==1.8.7.0

Answer (score 0):

run the command from inside the docker container. Divio somehow seem to have fixed this in their install